# Remove event listener in a CMS's common.js file

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm working on a clients Squarespace site and there is a function in the common.js file that is causing problems. The file is included in every site and is uneditable. My question is how do I properly run a removeEventListener() to stop it from firing?

```
1698: function(l, m, h) {
YUI.add("squarespace-plugin-scroll-lock", function(a) {
    a.namespace("Squarespace.Plugin").ScrollLock = a.Base.create("ScrollLock", a.Plugin.Base, [], {
        initializer: function(e) {
            var b = this.get("host"),
                c = b.getDOMNode();
            this.listener = function(d) {
                d.stopPropagation();
                if (!a.Lang.isNumber(c.scrollTop)) return d.preventDefault(), !1;
                var f = parseInt(b.getComputedStyle("height"), 10),
                    g = c.scrollTop,
                    f = c.scrollHeight - f,
                    e = d.wheelDelta || -d.detail;
                if (0 >= g && 0 < e || g >= f && 0 > e) return d.preventDefault(), !1
            };
            c.addEventListener ? (c.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.listener), c.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.listener), c.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", this.listener)) : c.attachEvent && c.attachEvent("onmousewheel", this.listener)
        },
        destructor: function() {

            var a = this.get("host").getDOMNode();
            a.removeEventListener ? (a.removeEventListener("mousewheel", this.listener), a.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.listener), a.removeEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", this.listener)) : a.detachEvent && a.detachEvent("onmousewheel", this.listener)
        }
    }, {
        NS: "ScrollLock",
        ATTRS: {}
    })
}, "1.0", {
    requires: ["base", "plugin", "node"]
})
```